# Angular5 - ngx-datatable scrolling with an variable limit isn´t working

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-scroll-with-limit

if start in stackblitz you see 5 rows with header and footer. I want to change with the select-box above the count of visible rows. if you select 15 it changes not directly the table. But if you resize the browser, then you get the right 15 rows with header and footer.
WHY is this only after resize the browser?

Comment: Just scrolling up and down the the table results in various console errors for me. Not sure whether they are related, but maybe fixing them helps? Besides that, the resizing probably triggers some kind of recalculation/resizing happening internally, maybe you can trigger that wen changing your "size" value.

Comment: yes, there are a problem with the scrolling. i just forked this stackblitz and there was this special loading of results.